# Segmentations with equal length on a hyperbola

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry, hyperbolic-functions

How can I divide a hyperbola or one of its branches into many segmentations with equal **length = *l* along the curve**. hyperbola can be express as:
$x^2/a^2 - y^2/b^2 = 1$

How to compute the *x, y* for the seperation points?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arclength along a hyperbola doesn't have an expression in terms of familiar functions; e.g. it is given by an "[elliptic integral of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral#Incomplete_elliptic_integral_of_the_second_kind)" (wikipedia link).

So, unless you happen to have access to (or can write) a function that computes elliptic integrals, you're going to have to use a numeric method to approximate arclength.

---

[Here is a WolframAlpha expression](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+sqrt(b%5E2+cosh(u)%5E2+%2B+a%5E2+sinh(u)%5E2)+du) for the indefinite integral of arclength of the hyperbola parametrized by $(a \cosh(u), b \sinh(u))$

[Here is a mathworld reference](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Hyperbola.html) for hyperbola mensuration formulas, which also includes the formula for arclength.rent notation conventions for the elliptic integral)